# Can't allow_url_fopen

Tags: centos

On Centos 7 with Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.4 I would like to turn on allow_url_fopen 
In php.ini:
`allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = On`
but it still looks like not eneabled.
I use this test: tt.php

```
 <?php
```

$a = ini_get('allow_url_open');
if ($a === true)
    echo 'allow_url_open is ON';
else
    echo 'allow_url_open is OFF';

And is shows:

```
allow_url_open is OFF
```

I try Php 5.6 and the result is same.
How to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you restart it? What else is installed on the system?

Answer (score 0):

Things to keep in mind:

1. Did you restart your Apache service after the change?
2. Your script is wrong. The ini_get() function returns a string, not a boolean. Try instead compare it using '=='.
3. Why don't you use phpinfo() instead?
4. Check [this link](http://br.php.net/ini_get) to get some examples of how to use the ini_get() function. :)

Here's a right version for your script, as requested:

```
<?php
$option = ini_get('allow_url_fopen');
echo ($option == 0) ? "allow_url_fopen disabled" : "allow_url_fopen enabled";
?>
```

Best regards!

Comment: 1. Yes, I restart Apache.  2. Can you help me to edit this scrip? :-))

Comment: Just added it. =)

Comment: This script shows all time shows:allow_url_fopen enabled no matter you sent in php.ini On or Off.

Comment: I have also installed mariadb, shorewall, postfix.